# Downloading FileStream object doesn't open Download Dialog Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, reportingservices-2005

Well, I already tried a lot of stuff to solve this issue, but none did.

I developed a Reporting Service (2005) and deployed it.

This report will be used by everyone who access a website (it's a internet site, so, won't be accessed by intranet) developed on the framework 3.5 (but I think the framework's version is not the source of the problem).

I had other issues with authentication, and the workaround included the using of the FileStream class on my website.

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
rs.Url = "http://MyServer/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

arguments
byte[] result = null;
string reportPath = "/ReportLuiza/ReportContract";
string format = "PDF";

// Prepare report parameter.
ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
parameters[0].Name = "NMB_CONTRACT";
parameters[0].Value = txtNmbContractReport.Text;

string encoding;
string mimeType;
string extension;
Warning[] warnings = null;
string[] streamIDs = null;

ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, null);

rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "pt-br");
String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

try
{
   result = rs.Render(format, null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

   execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
}
catch (SoapException se)
{
    ShowMessage(se.Detail.OuterXml);
}

// Write the contents of the report to an pdf file.
try
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\report.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ShowMessage(ex.Message);
}
```

For this code, I had to add a WebReference to the .asmx file mentioned in it.

Both Report and WebSite are deployed/published on the same server with a IIS 7.5 version.

Is there an way where user can choose where it wants to save the .pdf file?

Any help will be appreciated.

If you need more information to help me, just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I understand this code is not providing the report to User at all. Rather everything is available on the server only and a user who has access to the Server's C drive can open report.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to combine the two `try-catch` blocks:

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
rs.Url = "http://MyServer/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

arguments
byte[] result = null;
string reportPath = "/ReportLuiza/ReportContract";
string format = "PDF";

// Prepare report parameter.
ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
parameters[0].Name = "NMB_CONTRACT";
parameters[0].Value = txtNmbContractReport.Text;

string encoding;
string mimeType;
string extension;
Warning[] warnings = null;
string[] streamIDs = null;

ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, null);

rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "pt-br");
String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

try
{
   result = rs.Render(format, null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

   execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
}
catch (SoapException se)
{
    ShowMessage(se.Detail.OuterXml);
}

// Write the contents of the report to an pdf file.
try
{
    /*
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\report.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
    */
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"report.pdf\"");
    Response.BinaryWrite(result);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ShowMessage(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thank @Abhinav. You saved my life, my job, my mother, my dog and my parrot.